# Send a file from Angular to Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-fullstack

I am creating a form to allow users to upload their files. I am using Angular for the front end and Node.js/MySQL for the backend. However, I am getting an error. When I try to send file from Angular to Node.js, the file doesn't get received. I read somewhere on stack overflow that one can send a file in the http headers. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

> xxxx.component.html (Angular)

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
 </div>
 <div class="custom-file">
   <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" [(ngModel)] = "fU" name = 
    "FileUpload" id="inputGroupFile01"
     aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" required>
     <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

> xxxx.component.ts (Angular)

```
private onCreatePosts(form: NgForm)
{
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/post', form.value)
    .subscribe(responseData => {
      console.log(responseData);
    }
    ,error => {
      this.connectionToServerFailed = true;
    });
 }
```

> Node.js

```
router.post("/post", (req, res) =>{
var fileupload = req.body.FileUpload;
console.log(fileupload);
console.log(fileupload.name);
})
```

Here's the output that I am getting when I try to upload a file:

> C:\fakepath\testfile.docx
> undefined

I have tried different things, but still unable to progress any further. Can anybody tell me why I am getting this error of undefined and fakepath.

EDIT: When I try to access the file, it only prints the path not the file. The angular Http request is only sending the path of the file not the file itself.
EDIT: Editing this question again so, that somebody can help. EDIT: I have tried working with a lot of different things but nothing is working for me. The node.js is only getting the path of the file, not the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files will not be part of the request out of the box; they have to be stored temporarily on disk or in memory in Node.js. Try something like multer: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/uploading-files-using-multer-on-server-in-nodejs-and-expressjs-5f4e621ccc67

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FormData`

```
private onCreatePosts(form: NgForm)
{
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", file, file.name)               //your file, file name
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/post', fd)
    .subscribe(responseData => {
      console.log(responseData);
    }
    ,error => {
      this.connectionToServerFailed = true;
    });
 }
```

**In node.js**

```
const fileupload = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let form = new IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, (err, field, files) => {
            fs.readFile(files.file.path, async (err, data) => {
                 // data is your file data
            })
        })
    }
    catch (e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you readFile in your node.js when you want to save it? I want to save that file in node.js after receiving it from Angular.

Comment: We are sending form from front end, so I have used IncomingForm to get the form from front end(angular) and parse it to get the form data

Comment: I already have a form in which I am taking other inputs, I want to add the add file option in that existing form. I have tried the method above, it's not working. It still prints the path only not the file itself.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this.

1. Without any `npm` packages
2. Using `npm i multer`

However, I will be discussing the 1st method rather than using multer.
Steps to upload via angular are as follows:

1. component.html

```
<input type="file" id="fileuploadPhoto" (change)="onPhotoUpload($event)">
<label for="fileuploadPhoto" class="custom-file-upload">
```

2. component.ts

```
onPhotoUpload(e) {
    var file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.target.files[0];
    var pattern = /image-*/;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (!file.type.match(pattern)) {
      alert('invalid format');
      return;
    }
    reader.onload = this._setUploadPhoto.bind(this);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

```
  _setUploadPhoto(e) {
    let reader = e.target;

    const result = reader.result;
    // this.openSnackBar(result.length,"OK")
    if (!result) {
      this.openSnackBar("Cannot read", "OK")
      this.imageSrcPhoto = '';
    }
    if (result.length > 400000) {
      this.openSnackBar("File size should be less than 300KB", "OK")
      this.imageSrcPhoto = '';
    }
    else {
      this.imageSrcPhoto = reader.result;
    }
  }
```

3. In service.ts use post method to pass the image we saved as base64 string

```
  addCustomer(data: Object) {
    return this.http.post(environment._customerAPI + '/addCustomer', data)
  }
```

In NodeJS (Based on MVC architecture)

1. Routes

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config()
}

/* =================================================================================================== */
/*                              Initialising Express & other dependencies                              */
/* =================================================================================================== */

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


/* =================================================================================================== */
/*                          Data server to handle data transfer & processing                           */
/* =================================================================================================== */

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "5mb" }));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
const custRoutes = require('./routes/customer');
app.use('/customer', custRoutes);
router.post('/addCustomer',cust.addCustomer)
```

2. The image upload controller

```
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports.imageUpload = (imgArray, imgName, foldername, misc = null) => {
    const IMG_PATH = process.env.ASSETS_DIR
    var dir = IMG_PATH + '/customer/';
    console.log(dir)
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }

    dir += foldername + '/';

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }

    var fullImageName;
    var Base64Data;
    var imagePathArray = [];

    imgArray.forEach(img => {
        fullImageName = dir + imgName;
        fullImageName += '_' + img.Idtype;
        fullImageName += '.png'

        imagePathArray.push(fullImageName)
        Base64Data = img.imageUrl.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");

        fs.writeFile(fullImageName, Base64Data, 'base64', function (err) {
            return { 'status': false, 'path': null };
        });
    });

    return { 'status': true, 'path': imagePathArray };
}
```